# How to load Laravel projects Directly after clicking links created in index.html using .htaccess?

Tags: php, laravel, xampp, laravel-8

**I am trying to create a website that contains other laravel projects(different versions) using .htaccess**

> index.html

```
<body>
    <ul>
      <li>
        <a href="Projects/Project1/">Project1</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Projects/Project2/">Project2</a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="Projects/Project3/">Project3</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </body>
```

> project1's .env for redirecting to project1

```
APP_URL=http://127.0.0.1:8000/AllProjects/Projects/Project1/
```

**I have also created .htacess file in every project and the code it contain**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews
    RewriteEngine On

    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ /public/index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

**Now the problem is I cannot see the website I see the directories, and I am doing this for the first time so I have no clue how to do it. Any help would be really appreciated, Thanks**

Comment: Are you using a linux server? Do you have access to your linux server? I can give you a better solution, what you are trying to do is very dangerous and not recommended at all.

Comment: You're most likely using Apache web server, so look into something called `virtual hosts`. You have project1.local and project2.local and that main index.html page. The project1.local, you `serve` that from that directory you gave: "AllProjects/Projects/Project1/", same goes for project 2. Then in your index.html, just point to `project1.local`, etc. Don't forget to edit your hosts file, just Google for how to do that

Comment: `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f` means if the requested filename does not exist so the condition will not pass if the requested directory exists (which is the case when someone requests `/`). Try making the .htaccess file look more like https://github.com/laravel/laravel/blob/9.x/public/.htaccess

Comment: Honestly speaking I didn't understood anything, I am very new to this